# Filling a hollow figurine

Tags: solidify-modifier

[image]I have this 3d image of Buddha's face. I want to3d print this but want to have it solid inside. However attached image is hollow. How to fill solid with such complex sculpture shapes. Online, I'm able to only find reference for filling geometrical shapes

Comment: You haven't attached an image so we can't see what you mean. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1):

The infill (amount of filling percentage of a 3D print) is usually controlled by your 3D print software. 3D models are usually hollow between and inner and outer faces to save on storing unnecessary data. If your model has an open end (like a cup), you will have to close the open face by selecting all the edges around the opening and filling (F on keyboard once all edges around the hole are highlighted/selected). This will create a new face connected to all the selected edges at the time of the operation. Your model will now be closed.

Comment: You can refer the image (that I missed to upload earlier) so that it is clear on what I'm asking. I understand the infill concept. Attached 3d object is hollow inside. If I try to fill by selecting mesh joints and fill (F on keyboard). It is randomly adding spike type of filling instead of solid fill

Comment: You could try extruding or bevelling the edges around the hole and joining any unattached vertices. Or you can make a cylinder with only one end face in the approximate shape of the hole, align it on top of the hole (like a bottle cap), move it down in z until the top is level, then do a Boolean modifier operation and select the cylinder as the model to add to the Buddha. Bad topology when modelling or importing scans causes all sorts of problems like this.